# How to create Projects/Tasks for Project Server 2003 via C#?

Tags: c#, project-server

I need to be able to create basic MS Project items (tasks, projects, resources, etc.) programmatically from my app to my Project Server 2003 install, and haven't found any good examples. Can anyone point me to some good references or have some sample code of connecting to the server and creating these items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developing against Project Server 2003 isn't the friendliest experience around, but I have worked a little bit with the PDS (Project Data Services) which is SOAP based

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa204408(office.11).aspx

It contains .NET samples there

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only programatic access to PS 2003 is through PWS.

I don't know if it would work, but you could try writing a managed extension for Microsoft Project 2003 (The client application) .There [is a managed API for MS Project 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa209377(office.11).aspx), and you might be able to leverage that to communicate with the server, get a project and update it all in code.

Good luck!